# Phoenixframework Poison encoder ignoring derive

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-poison

I have this model with a `has_many` directive. I'm trying to get all the values out of it and display them in a json response:

```
defmodule Heroico.Datacenter do
    use Heroico.Web, :model

    @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:id, :identifier, :city, :state, :country]}
    schema "datacenters" do
        field :identifier, :string
        field :city, :string
        field :state, :string
        field :country, :string

        belongs_to :provider, Heroico.Provider
        has_many :plans, Heroico.Plan

        timestamps()
    end

    ...
end
```

Controller:

```
def index(conn, _params, _current_user, _claims) do
    render conn, "index.json", datacenters: Repo.all(Datacenter)
end
```

View:

```
defmodule Heroico.DatacenterView do
    use Heroico.Web, :view

    def render("index.json", %{datacenters: datacenters}) do
        %{datacenters: datacenters}
    end
end
```

`lib/poison_encoder.ex`:

```
defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Any do
    def encode(%{__struct__: _} = struct, options) do
        map = struct
            |> Map.from_struct
            |> sanitize_map
        Poison.Encoder.Map.encode(map, options)
    end

    defp sanitize_map(map) do
        Map.drop(map, [:__meta__, :__struct__])
    end
end
```

As you can see, the `@derive` clearly states that only `[:id, :identifier, :city, :state, :country]` should be encoded yet I can't seem to get rid of this error:

`cannot encode association :plans from Heroico.Datacenter to JSON because the association was not loaded. Please make sure you have preloaded the association or remove it from the data to be encoded`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this locally. Could you try running `mix clean` once and restart the Elixir process and see if this still happens?

Comment: Same result. I tried switch from `only` to `except` for the `@derive` but nothing changed. It's like the @derive is totally ignored.

Comment: What does this return: `Poison.Encoder.impl_for(%Heroico.Datacenter{})`?

Comment: That returns `Poison.Encoder.Any`

Comment: That confirms that `Poison.Decoder` is not being implemented for `Datacenter`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: Can you try reproducing this in a brand new Phoenix app? I copied the `@derive` line into one of my app and `impl_for` returns the correct module for my model. Also, if you implement `Poison.Encoder` for that model manually (like you did for `Any`: `defimpl Poison.Encoder, for: Heroico.Datacenter do`), does that work?

Comment: That prints out `Poison.Encoder.Heroico.Datacenter` but the error is still there `cannot encode association :plans`. I'll try with a new project and see if the error is still there.

Comment: You'll have to `Map.drop` `:plans` (and `:provider`, etc) in the manual implementation. That should work.

Comment: Feels like a hack (since `@derive` is clearly not instructed to pull out `:plans`) but works. Can you make this an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Well, `Map.drop` is not a hack; that's how you'd implement `Poison.Encoder` manually (if that's what you meant by `feels like a hack`). For whatever reason, `@derive` is not working at all. Were you able to reproduce this `@derive` problem in a brand new project?